# Does the Fourier expansion of the j-function have any prime coefficients?

Tags: nt.number-theory

Title asks it: Does the Fourier expansion of the  j-function have any prime coefficients?

A superabundance of congruences involving primes up to 13 rule out many candidates, but calculation suggests that primes $p>13$ occur as divisors at frequencies (about?) $1/p$.

But
$$c_{71}=278775024890624328476718493296348769305198947=(353) (5533876049689057963) (142708463580969897033673)$$
so that might count as a near miss.

That said, though composite, none of $c_{1319},c_{1559},c_{1871},c_{2111},c_{2231},c_{3239},c_{3551}, 
c_{4271}, c_{4799}, c_{5471}$,... has a factor less than 100.

Comment: The coefficients $c_{n}$ for $1 \leq n \leq 5 \cdot 10^{5}$ are all composite. Given that $c_{n} \sim e^{4 \pi \sqrt{n}}/(\sqrt{2} n^{3/4})$ it seems likely that there are some prime coefficients.

Comment: Tabulation of the coefficients with many links to the lliterature at https://oeis.org/A000521 Factorizations up to $n=1000$ given at http://www.asahi-net.or.jp/~KC2H-MSM/mathland/matha1/

Comment: @JeremyRouse In fact, given that growth rate, our naive expectation should be infinitely many prime coefficients.

Comment: I discovered a bug in my program (a type error) that leads to all the coefficients being labelled "not prime".

Comment: The sum over the primes $p>13$ of $1/p$ (your expected frequencies) is divergent, so maybe a study of the relative frequency $f_{k}$ of the coefficients having exactly $k$ prime factors counted with multiplicity could shed some light on the problem.

Comment: Jeremy: were you by any chance using Sage and were bitten by is_prime(QQ(2)) returning False?

Comment: I was using Magma, but the error was similar. (I created $j$ as an element in a power series ring over the rationals.)

Comment: I've been computing j-coefficients using Mahler's recurrence.  But getting to a million coefficients with Maple is taking days...I started the calculation shortly after I made the post.  Maybe my computer is slow...but are other folks using a better algorithm?

Comment: @DavidFeldman Yes, I will soon share some code and a short writeup.

Comment: @DavidFeldman See my latest update.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There are seven prime values (passing a BPSW test) of $c_n$ with $n \le 2 \cdot 10^7$, at indices 457871, 685031, 1029071, 1101431, 9407831, 11769911, and 18437999.

For a writeup about the computations, source code, and the prime numbers themselves, see:
https://github.com/fredrik-johansson/jfunction

The first prime $c_{457871}$ is the following 3689-digit number:

30801636514011810817665318374658229108845878479020424564852145048550477094266397753615620563343543122809859646561082297428127434662591162587465688189470673559500946738365120052237063677089165938711865291826029106118944935275575747924692016273156986404534483801538929131770513483035012136870394657959401728135298020394188493171098233244180987908576898694823463564573986521378977434641833939268448907892425327423931702787985965542437137823321051154070271812702040044018249180573203850835848455588503282760349067467783417988439399728717693269653344946303351200847243267479008953480983893357261716684979093234554524907570654175153716092013381021033631140271230374127359907711968372522745844402375355449952404485703394467619855566837872874898909971592754384802113052943616244616228982238122927893868687205058321497136583843454449483568143398274104240118934930464297655670020151675237805373543868606164624359906981163728280265160187710553222515223577715624809615213830941718538338330718318212962253165154784990727034694055424785446779353587418545233599512401297307560287330719685869795522920270669609498639686158362603820371777436303198350821510562028940026062291473250204511985677264132923030166903832835499326969147438699601413777550018800825631136927531190121891919023537853918707520543367800297170322643557011053113196699442392677721251164071912545596204918917566579754931649583289900867072630307177448327512748573948720052532426026582228531694404885199310535255097152264726060203165225244982020696634699998363392968546865623955653923292400203238704016331998301098882719280237294694368706187727194309664172903851082095220551328392538250319846241916349485122880753951745944930504836900929002975743487891022913325212927877123283110371004511930228354316650588540693893785256904915901446318107624914828072059779823732136657855374843120155979700684426795681799949828354496446059153417627020927839115150227802126261918915561804876068184778844391781134858921611498880947743310539662060436623031296503497690935576519684398269951037522254928920040638913033916447480995451172728711833839757712418893132702856601768693707767408660072694546475350179623544013680656723320135856226549734491873157405584154845513711221581080660024268777736123563250061564832634510929167076111162819878757339574946474890631427413494266622011134541083389565676533915214975782362935488902596227893270340685189472412328774565836766141144309983845007818359559400419277334332676913295096744471767890050480297665094988593656013858404531156346968039028944208325870737014099138274367178622028282421548639862174878971583355345514824564041789417768026191489674685601130884770272042320774286085741557976163690129647685531361972350643878463985533720888119015787469601005630621659687749812528402893568495431951749454436584549713954945990865871059056586397539337257860037142247888078726810588665972975365062119719322236620399267595421045468328581519496916075539958247075033250213251987450634988759698630929366797978086037651833328039578740169593342409162117195011259429537049154618053581738781731898468529654264215451362063751162610494664217028387863630499363451607405876105244341222047086047630946033922722790116254686279821386138836326264599571591967081705529398847838399554521937548523334357827287180353919911626556542110462725508733594289737987833526697420630616509010365868192637613354631155273335447830149024265581051436057754643260886600218454986343035650276055047068090749733940363539512760186969985697586068479926077515927351409212093813617210155525035138051400826519032339949113881712130873854263099726139035786383205124051644483087596049043497124737908938233702928805190964560673396398573801431769834039050534841422792714076699

Comment: FWIW: Mathematica confirms that the two numbers listed above are prime.

Comment: By strong pseudoprime, do you mean that the primality would be ensured by the veracity of GRH?

Comment: @SylvainJULIEN Not sure what method Fredrik used, but Pari GP (and hence also Sage) use the [Baillie-PSW primality test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baillie%E2%80%93PSW_primality_test) for pseudoprimality. No failures of this test are known, but I don't think any standard conjectures guarantee its correctness. According to the article Mathematica's PrimeQ also uses this test.

Comment: I checked with Pari and Flint which both implement (possibly slightly different versions of) BPSW which has no known counterexamples. In any case, these numbers are small enough that they can be certified prime in reasonable time (hours or days).

Comment: Fantastic.  Thanks.  Proving now that infinitely many such primes exist seems very difficult.

Comment: @Wojowu: is this test faster than Miller-Rabin's?

Comment: I am running an ECPP test on $c_{457871}$.

Comment: How many digits are these numbers, please?

Comment: @GerryMyerson See the information in the added link.

Comment: The ECPP test completed - $c_{457871}$ is prime. Primo 4.3.2 took 11336 seconds to verify it (running on six cores on a fairly old machine).

Comment: I don't see anything at that github page that would answer my question. Anyway, how hard is it to fill in the blanks for me? $c_{685031}$ has ____ digits. $c_{1029071}$ has ____ digits. And so on.

Comment: @GerryMyerson See Table 2 in paper.pdf in the paper directory. You can also get the numbers themselves from the data directory: data/j_685031.txt etc. But to fill in the blanks: the six primes found so far have 3689, 4513, 5532, 5723, 16734 and 18718 digits.

Comment: Good. Many thanks.